How to prove the following integral is positive?
Would someone like to help me to prove
$$
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} t \left(\dfrac{\sin(nt)}{\sin(t)}\right)^3 dt >0,
$$
where $n$ is a positive integer.
I split the region in $(0, \pi/n)$ and others. But I fail to prove it.
While I do not know how is it?

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

What do you think the lower bound should be? @user1776247

Indeed, I know the upper bound is $k_1n$. I guess the lower bound is also $k_2 n$. But I only need it is zero.
